# Jquery placing a text in x and y co ordinate

Tags: jquery

Say i've an value x = 100 and y = 26 with a div height and width equal to 500.

How do i place a text in that x and y co ordinate ?

What is the in built method that does this ?

x=Math.floor(Math.random()*500);
y=Math.floor(Math.random()*500);

I've to place text in this x and y co ordinates.
Thanks

Comment: do you want to take coordinates from a center of the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to add a new element at a particular position in another element.
You can do this by setting css properties using `.css` function in jQuery.

```
function addText(txt, x, y) {
    $('<div>').css({
        left: x,
        top: y
    }).html(txt).appendTo('#container');
}

addText("Hello", 50, 100);
```

container element should have `position:relative` and child elements should have `position:absolute` in css

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p5QSd/

Comment: :http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/ Tried this but this is not working.Can you explain your code why two container.

Comment: :Each time i a text to be placed in random places with in the div height and width.

Comment: made a few changes - repalced `txt` with "hello", added "position:absolute", reduced 1000 to 500 so that the element will be in visible area, replaced "container" with "test".

Comment: :Text is over lapping and it is also going out of div,how do i fix this http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/5/

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new element and then move it with CSS:

```
$('<div />', {
    text: 'Hello'
}).css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '100px',
    top: '26px'
}).appendTo('#your-div');
```

`#your-div` should also have `position: relative;` in its CSS to make your new element position relative to its parent, not the document.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/5Sfhh/**

Comment: 1. This element needs to be appended to the body, 2. `text` is not a css attribute. How about `.text('Hello')`.

Comment: may be coordinates are from center of the div? :)

Comment: @nbrooks: I had `text` in `.css()` for a second or so, but I edited it afterwards.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst: Go and learn better jquery element construction.

Comment: @Blender Oh well that makes more sense. Looks good now anyway +1

Comment: @Blender:Can you correct this ? jsfiddle.net/q58HK  Each time i ant text to be placed in random places with in the div height and width.

Comment: @Blender:Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/5/.I need to solve tow problems,text is going out of div and it is over lapping.How do i fix this both?

Comment: @redasaw: Try solving the problem yourself first.